# How can i use double click in Highcharts and get that data

Tags: highcharts, categories, double-click, linechart

how to use double click get the Category, name, y of a line of a line chart?

i tries use customEvents plugin.
but i don't know get those data in line chart
in the column chart, i use below code is okay.

```
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
    point: {
        events: {
            dblclick: function(e) {
                var c = this.point.category;
                var y = this.point.options.y;
                var n = this.point.series.name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the plugin, so please check if all works as you expect.

Comment: the customEvents plugin is download from official recently

Comment: i downloaded same version customEvents from another website, it was work. thanks

Comment: The newest is always here: http://blacklabel.github.io/custom_events/customEvents.js

Comment: I've upgraded to HighCharts 4 and the custom events plugin appears to have stopped working. Has the plugin been updated?

Comment: Please replicate your example as live, because the example from previous link, is based on HC4.